# Eager loading with scope in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I found many questions with similar title but none of them could solve my question.

I have a model `Program` which has many `Videos`:

```
class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :videos
  ...
end
```

Then I have scope in `Video`:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :program

  scope :trailer, -> { where(video_type: 0) }
  ...
end
```

Firstly, when I have a list of programs and want to access videos, I have no N+1 program with `include` method:

```
> @programs.includes(:videos).map { |p| p.videos.size }
  Program Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "programs".* FROM "programs"  ORDER BY "programs"."id" ASC LIMIT 10
  Video Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "videos".* FROM "videos" WHERE "videos"."program_id" IN (8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17)
```

However, when I try to get the scope, it will touch Database again:

```
> @programs.includes(:videos).map { |p| p.videos.trailer }
  Program Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "programs".* FROM "programs"  ORDER BY "programs"."id" ASC LIMIT 10
  Video Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "videos".* FROM "videos" WHERE "videos"."program_id" IN (8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17)
  Video Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "videos".* FROM "videos" WHERE "videos"."program_id" = $1 AND "videos"."video_type" = $2  ORDER BY "videos"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["program_id", 8], ["video_type", 0]]
  Video Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "videos".* FROM "videos" WHERE "videos"."program_id" = $1 AND "videos"."video_type" = $2  ORDER BY "videos"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["program_id", 9], ["video_type", 0]]
  Video Load (12.4ms)  SELECT  "videos".* FROM "videos" WHERE "videos"."program_id" = $1 AND "videos"."video_type" = $2  ORDER BY "videos"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["program_id", 10], ["video_type", 0]]
  Video Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "videos".* FROM "videos" WHERE "videos"."program_id" = $1 AND "videos"."video_type" = $2  ORDER BY "videos"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["program_id", 11], ["video_type", 0]]
  Video Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "videos".* FROM "videos" WHERE "videos"."program_id" = $1 AND "videos"."video_type" = $2  ORDER BY "videos"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["program_id", 12], ["video_type", 0]]
  Video Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "videos".* FROM "videos" WHERE "videos"."program_id" = $1 AND "videos"."video_type" = $2  ORDER BY "videos"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["program_id", 13], ["video_type", 0]]
  Video Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "videos".* FROM "videos" WHERE "videos"."program_id" = $1 AND "videos"."video_type" = $2  ORDER BY "videos"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["program_id", 14], ["video_type", 0]]
  Video Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "videos".* FROM "videos" WHERE "videos"."program_id" = $1 AND "videos"."video_type" = $2  ORDER BY "videos"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["program_id", 15], ["video_type", 0]]
  Video Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "videos".* FROM "videos" WHERE "videos"."program_id" = $1 AND "videos"."video_type" = $2  ORDER BY "videos"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["program_id", 16], ["video_type", 0]]
  Video Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "videos".* FROM "videos" WHERE "videos"."program_id" = $1 AND "videos"."video_type" = $2  ORDER BY "videos"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["program_id", 17], ["video_type", 0]]
```

You can see it will load DB many times which lead to a bad performance.

```
#<Benchmark::Tms:0x007f95faa8fab0 @label="", @real=0.02663199999369681, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.0, @utime=0.019999999999999574, @total=0.019999999999999574>
```

---

One solution I can think of is to convert videos to array and search the array:

```
> @programs.includes(:videos).map { |program| program.videos.to_ary.select { |v| v.video_type == 0 } }
  Program Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "programs".* FROM "programs" WHERE "programs"."id" IN (8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17)
  Video Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "videos".* FROM "videos" WHERE "videos"."program_id" IN (17, 16, 13, 12, 11, 9, 8, 15, 14, 10)
```

The performance is better but the code is complex.

```
#<Benchmark::Tms:0x007f95faac8720 @label="", @real=0.006901999993715435, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.0, @utime=0.010000000000000675, @total=0.010000000000000675>
```

---

Another solution I can think of, is to add a new `has_many` in `Program` for scope:

```
class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :videos
  has_many :trailer_videos, -> { where(video_type: 0) }, class: 'Video'
  ...
end
```

Then if I `includes` and call the new relation directly, it will eager load as well.

```
> @programs.includes(:trailer_videos).map { |program| program.trailer_videos }
  Program Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "programs".* FROM "programs" WHERE "programs"."id" IN (8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17)
  Video Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "videos".* FROM "videos" WHERE "videos"."video_type" = $1 AND "videos"."program_id" IN (17, 16, 13, 12, 11, 9, 8, 15, 14, 10)  [["video_type", 0]]
```

The benchmark is below, which is super fast:

```
#<Benchmark::Tms:0x007f95fdea96c0 @label="", @real=0.004801000002771616, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.0, @utime=0.009999999999999787, @total=0.009999999999999787>
```

However, in this way, it will make the `Program` model so heavy. Because for each scope in `Video`, I need to added a related association in `Program`.

---

Therefore, I am looking for a better solution, which will keep the scope logic inside of `Video`, but without N+1 problem.

Cheers

Comment: Your method of adding `has_many :trailer_videos` is the best way to counter your situation. I don't see any drawback in adding more such associations to the model.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I said, IMO your approach of adding the `has_many :trailer_videos, -> { where(video_type: 0) }, class: 'Video'` is the simple and best way to counter your problem. I don't see any drawback in adding more such associations to the model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For example, if I have a page, for each program, I will 1) display all videos' url, and 2) show the `trailer` video's image. So do you think `@programs.includes(:videos, :trailer_videos)` is the best way? A video in `trailer` will be loaded twice.

Comment: @Stephen In that case why including `:trailer_videos` again? `:videos` will contain all videos including the trailer videos. isn't?

Comment: Because you need to call `trailer` and it will load DB. For example, `<%= program.trailer_videos.size %>/<%= program.videos.size %>`. Then it will load twice

Comment: `Video Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "videos".* FROM "videos" WHERE "videos"."program_id" IN (17, 16, 13, 12, 11, 9, 8, 15, 14, 10)`
  `Video Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "videos".* FROM "videos" WHERE "videos"."video_type" = $1 AND "videos"."program_id" IN (17, 16, 13, 12, 11, 9, 8, 15, 14, 10)  [["video_type", 0]]`

Comment: After thinking a lot I finally choose this way. Even if load twice, it is better than load N+1 times. Thanks.

Comment: Notice that it works only with `preload` (and `includes`) but not with `eager_load`

Answer (score 5):

In Rails `Associations` have an optional scope parameter that accepts a lambda that is applied to the `Relation` (see https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many-label-Scopes)

So you could write your models as:

```
# app/models/video.rb
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :program
  scope :trailer, -> { where(video_type: 0) }
  ...
end

# app/models/program.rb
class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :videos
  has_many :trailer_videos, -> { trailer }, class: 'Video'
  ...
end
```

This way you could keep the definition of the scope in `Video` and reuse it from `Program`.

Answer (score 4):

A solution is to use `merge` with `eager_load`:

```
@programs.eager_load(:videos).merge(Video.trailer).map { |p| p.videos.size }
```

It produces only one query.

Comment: The problem of this solution is that programs without trailer videos are excluded from the query. (This restriction comes from `LEFT OUTER JOIN` by eager_load.)

Answer (score 2):

If the video types are known to the programmer you can use an [`ActiveRecord::Enum`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) and some simple metaprogrammng to create assocations programatically for each possible value in the enum.

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum video_type: [:trailer, :promo, :foo, :bar]
end

class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
  # this creates trailer_videos etc assocations
  Video.video_types.each do |key, int| 
    # eval is needed since we need to dynamically create 
    # the lamba for each type
    has_many "#{key}_videos".to_sym, eval "->{ Video.send(#{key}) }"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my question is not focused on how to create `has_many` association dynamically.